# How connect multiple IBM watson services in one?

Tags: ibm-watson

In IBM Watson I want to use 2 services say speech-to-text and conversation, I want to communicate between these services. If I use this service indpendently I require to call speech-to-text and then to conversation i.e. network cycle is increased. Is there way to keep this services in container and I only call the container after that call my speech-to-text and conversation communicate internally with each other rather I making an explicit call to each service.

Answer (score 1):

Watson Speech to Text and Conversation are separate services, so you will have to invoke each separately.

Answer (score 1):

You need to call each of the APIs for speech-to-text and then for conversation individually. But if you wish you can bundle them together in a container at your development code.It works for me. Hope this helps.